# Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, database, xampp, localhost, mysql-connect

I'm trying to connect to a localhost database using php.

but it's shown

> Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp2\htdocs\wikifiesto\wf-insertcase.php on line 7
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp2\htdocs\wikifiesto\wf-insertcase.php on line 7
> error connecting to database

the structure of server, user, pass is localhost, pma, ' '

here's my code with the name 'wf-insertcase.php':

```
<?php
define('dbuser', 'pma');
define('dbpass', '');
define('dbserver', 'localhost');
define('dbname', 'wikifiesto');

$conn = mysql_connect(dbuser, dbpass, dbserver, dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die('error connecting to database');
}

echo 'you have created case';
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have bad params order in your function. DB server has to be the first param.

```
$conn = mysql_connect(dbserver, dbuser, dbpass);
```

DB name isn't allowed there, use `mysql_select_db(dbname)`.

All mysql_* are deprecated, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php and `MySQLi` extension.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(dbserver, dbuser, dbpass, dbname);
             ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Warning "No such host is known" occur because "Host" is not set properly.

Please replace the following lines of your code

```
$conn = mysql_connect(dbuser, dbpass, dbserver, dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die('error connecting to database');
}
```

with

```
$conn = mysql_connect(dbserver,dbuser,dbpass);

if (!$conn){
    die('error connecting to database');
}else{
    mysql_select_db(dbname, $conn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be broken soon, as those functions are [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli) and will be removed soon from PHP.

If you still want to use them, use the right order for [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

```
$mysql_handler = mysql_connect($host, $user,  $pass);
mysql_select_db($database_name, $mysql_handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Mysql`

```
<?php
$dbuser = 'pma';
$dbpass = '';
$dbserver = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'wikifiesto';


$conn = mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass);//Connecting to localhost

$db = mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);//connecting database
```

In `mysqli`

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname)//MySQLi Procedural
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysqli instead of mysql  has deprecated

```
<?php
define('DBUSER', 'pma');
define('DBPASS', '');
define('DBSERVER', 'localhost');
define('DBNAME', 'wikifiesto');

$conn = new mysqli(DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);

if (!$conn) {
    die('error connecting to database');
}

echo 'you have created case';
?>
```

you have some following non-standard things/errors

1. NAME of Constant must be CAPITAL
2. use of mysql instead of mysqli
3. the order of parameter must be  as

   - host
   - db user
   - db user pass
   - db name